# How to find the kth smallest element in an unsorted array or its segment?

Tags: arrays, rust

Does Rust have a function to find the *k*th smallest element in an array or a segment of an array?

(Similar to `std::nth_element` in C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function in `std`.

However, you can use [the crate `order_stat`](https://huonw.github.io/order-stat/order_stat/index.html), which offers [a `kth` function](https://huonw.github.io/order-stat/order_stat/fn.kth.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes (since rust 1.49)

[select_nth_unstable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.select_nth_unstable)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
fn find_smallest_int(arr: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut small_number=arr.to_vec();
    small_number.sort();
    small_number[0]
}
```

Comment: This has incorrect asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Well, not incorrect, just inefficient.